# Unable to establish Cassandra connection in R using RJDBC

Tags: cassandra, rjdbc

> casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/quantum_cassandra")
>   12:31:02.140 [main] DEBUG c.datastax.driver.jdbc.SessionHolder - Final Properties to Connection: {user=, password=, portNumber=9042, databaseName=quantum_cassandra, serverName=localhost}
>   12:31:02.140 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Starting new cluster with contact points [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042]
>   12:31:02.230 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized and ready
>   12:31:02.232 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
>   12:31:02.315 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing schema
>   12:31:02.322 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
>   12:31:02.323 [New I/O worker #4] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Not terminating Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true]: there are still pending requests
>   12:31:02.325 [New I/O worker #4] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Not terminating Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true]: there are still pending requests
>   12:31:02.329 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] has already terminated
>   12:31:02.331 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] error on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 connection, no more host to try
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:103) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:140) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:158) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>           at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.messageReceived(Connection.java:734) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler.java:36) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar:na]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>   12:31:02.337 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Shutting down
>   12:31:02.352 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver - Final Properties to Connection: {user=, password=, portNumber=9042, databaseName=quantum_cassandra, serverName=localhost}
>   12:31:02.381 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver - Final Properties to Connection: {portNumber=9042, databaseName=quantum_cassandra, serverName=localhost}
>   Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  :
>     java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-2147483648)!

Could any one please help on this issue .

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",list.files("C:/Program Files/DataStax Community/apache-cassandra/lib",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9042/dbname")
result <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select tablename from columnname")
```

hope this would work